# Python reading file and then converting into Matrix

Tags: python

lets say I have one file in CSV, which has two columns, first column contains the image values in integer i.e., 28 x 28, and second column has label. How an I read this file. numpy.load and numpy.loadtxt both fails. I have to read column 1 and then convert into array of 784.

Comment: How does it fail?  Do you have a specific error message?  And could you share a couple lines of the file?

Comment: when I used numpy.loadtxt:     return float(x)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '70 80 82 72 58 58 60 63 54 58 60 48 89 ...

Comment: one easy way would be, use csv package to read the data, and create dataframe with some comprehension technique.

Comment: Junaid please update your question with that information.  I think you're parsing the text incorrectly and someone will quickly identify how to fix it.

Comment: csv package or maybe use pandas.read_csv() to read the file into dataframe, then transform dataframe to matrices and label list

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone who responded in comment section. My problem is solved by following code

```
Y = numpy.genfromtxt('training.csv',delimiter= " ",dtype=numpy.uint8);
```